# AutoLayout for only iPad application

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout

I would like to start my application that need to support for only iPad devices. Now, my question is do I need to use the Autolayout functionality?

What am thinking is as my app supports only iPad,no need to use the autolayout because all the ipad devices uses same size classes.

Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: size classes may be same but not device sizes ...

Comment: so it is mandatory to use Autolayout?

Comment: no ... you have to use autolayout to adapt different ipad device sizes .. thats my view on your question

Comment: _"What am thinking is as my app supports only iPad,no need to use the autolayout because all the ipad devices uses same size classes."_, you must not thing like that; especially e.g. if you want to support multitasking on iPad – so you should use auto-layout as _default_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use size classes even if you are using only iPad device as target for your application. There are some reasons why you have to use the size classes :

1) iPad have diff screen sized and resolutions as well. [check them Out here.](http://iosres.com/)

2) The iPad multitasking feature is there from ios 9 so you need to resize your views according to that and that will need size classes [check it out here.](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202070)

**NOTE :** if you are using autolayout then no need to use size classes but size classes are important [you can check the importance of the size classes and its working in apple's design guide line (here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

Answer (score 1):

ipad has different device size like 768 x 1024 and 1024 x 1366 (ipad pro) etc. so, you should use autolayout to manage it for every ipad device.